# What reference is needed to use GetEncoder()?

Tags: c#, drawing, codec

I am trying to save an image with a specific quality parameters and following this [example from Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

I can't find a way to use `GetEncoder()` like shown on this line 
`ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

What reference do I need to use this function?

I tried going to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoder?view=netframework-4.7.2) and tried to use `System.Text.Encoding, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Read the page again. `GetEncoder` is defined in it.

Comment: Yes, that's where GetEncoder is defined, but that has to do with string/text encoding. If you poke around in the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace and its classes, you can find similarly named methods, but not that one. It seems closer to what you want. Where did you get your code snippet from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetEncoder()` is manually defied in the given example using `ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();` to implement it.